# Tobasco ice-cream and air warriors in an (Anime?) animated movie?

Tags: animation, fantasy, anime, identify-this-movie

When I was a child, we rented a children's movie one day from Jumbo Video during the 1980's. My mother slept through it, but my sister and I watched it. It was definitely animated, and may have been Japanese/Anime. It was a sort of action-fantasy movie.

I recall that air/wind played an important part in the movie as though the characters were air-warriors or wind-riders, or some such. I also recall an iconic image from the movie (either from the movie itself, or more likely, from the cover of the tape) being of a bunch of characters riding large animals towards the camera with wind and sand blowing behind them (something like the—very—crude drawing below). I forgot to draw it, but in this picture, they were running through some sort of dusty valley, so the picture should have had some cliffs on the sides.

Another uniquely identifying scene I remember was of a boy and girl in a cave, wherein one of them (I believe it was the girl) eat some ice cream that turned out to contain Tabasco/hot sauce/jalapeños, after which she spat it out and gasped for water.

Does anyone know what movie this was?

[image]

Comment: What year was it when you saw this?  Do you recall what channel you may have seen it on?

Comment: @DForck42, Huh? I said we rented it from the video-store, not on television. And like the tag says, it was from the 80's.

Comment: @iandotkelly, thanks. I have about 0.003 artistic ability, but to be honest, it is actually a pretty good representation of what it looked like.

Comment: Ahh, I guess I just missed that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm *almost* tempted to say it's "Warriors of the Wind", which is a bastardized version of the anime classic [Nausicaä of the Valley of the Wind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nausica%C3%A4_of_the_Valley_of_the_Wind_%28film%29).

[image: Warriors of the Wind cover]

Everything sort of matches your description, though I'm having trouble with the Tabasco ice cream. In the original Japanese version there was a scene where Nausicaa and Asbel are eating nuts inside an underground cavern, they turn out to be really really bitter. But I'm not sure if that scene made it to the Warriors of the Wind version.

Comment: It's almost certainly it. +1 Two people eating something in a cave that turns out be surprisingly awful definitely fits. The cover definitely looks right (and familiar). I'm a little shocked at the cast listing that IMDB has for the English version; I suspect that it's not accurate (or that it's for a recent remake or something). Google didn't turn up anything about the ice-cream, so I'll try to find a copy to check it out. Oh, and I guess those were wings, not gully walls. `:-)`

Comment: Yeah I think you're looking at the cast for the recent Disney English dub released in 2005. The 80's dub (Warriors of the Wind) had no such star studded cast, but still managed a very good performance IMO. Cam Clarke (80's TMNT Leonardo, Liquid Snake, Kaneda from the original Akira dub ... etc) played the boy in the cave, named Prince Milo in WotW. See if this jogs your memory: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CpmlUmJBdsA

Comment: Yes, the cold, barrenness definitely fits. It seems that the IMDB has merged the listings for all three versions into the same page for some reason. :roll: Also, the Wikipedia page for this says that Miyazaki suggested that people just forget the English version existed. Oops; I'm *trying* to remember it. `:-D`

Comment: LOL I might be in the minority here, but I *liked* WotW. Or at least I liked the voice cast. Not a big fan of the cuts and changes they made. There's an amusing story/legend that says that when Disney approached Miyazaki for the re-dubbing rights, he sent them a Katana with a note simply saying "no cuts!".

Comment: Yes, I found that part amusing. When I read the part about the sword, I thought he meant it as a threat, but he may not have.

Comment: I cannot seem to determine whether the ice-cream scene was in *Warriors of the Wind*, so it may be the case that we rented two movies and I am mixing them up. (I do recall sinking into the couch and falling asleep, so I probably woke up somewhere in the middle of the second one.) I’ll accept this because it was definitely one of them and I cannot find anything about the other one.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a long shot, but could it be [Windaria](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windaria)?

Plot summary-

> The mountainous kingdom of Paro and the coastal city-state of Itha had
>   been at peace for over a century. They would have remained that way
>   but for the ambitions of Paro's power-hungry king. Paro invaded Itha,
>   despite the love between Jill, Paro's prince, and Ahanas, Itha's
>   princess. Caught between duty and emotion, the star-crossed lovers
>   were forced to fight a war to its bitter conclusion. Isu was a simple
>   farmer from the neutral village of Saki, but he saved Itha from being
>   destroyed by a spy from Paro, and found himself hungering for wealth
>   and glory that the Ithan monarchy could provide. Agents from Paro made
>   him an offer to fulfill his wishes, and he left his wife Marin behind
>   in what would turn into a battlefield between the two kingdoms.

Comment: Not bad, but no. *Windaria* is to cutesy and colorful. This one was a little blander in color and characters were not so tall and skinny with pert noses (i.e., Sailor-Moonesque). Plus, *Windaria* has a green valley and tree instead of wind, and the only thing I can find to *Windaria* having ice-cream is that is was in a freezer, not in a cave.